# PHP exec() in Ubuntu -- is there a limitation to the size of arguments you can pass in?

Tags: php, bash, ubuntu, background-process

I'm seeing "getconf ARG_MAX" from command line return a big number (2,097,152 bytes), and the argument I'm passing exec is a fraction of that (229,650), but my exec keeps dying and I can't figure out why. It works with smaller params passed into it.

Example code:
    $strReallyLongParamList = 'ARG1 ARG2-IS-200K ARG3 ARG4';
    exec('/path/to/my/background-process.php '.$strReallyLongParamList);
    //logging from by background-process.php never happened... code seems to have died on exec call

Is PHP limited internally or does it just pass everything through to Ubuntu?

I've since chunked my exec calls into smaller batches and all works grand, so it does seem that I was hitting some type of limit in PHP exec.

Comment: some example code would be nice, please edit your question

Comment: Maybe you'd be better off putting all the logic into a shell script and executing that via `exec()` ?

Comment: If you even have to *think* about the fact if your argument list is too long, you should really consider using stdin to pass those long arguments...

Comment: I'm having the same issue with drush command and --structure-tables-list="field*" where there are hundreds of tables starting with field. any idea where that 229650 number comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this article: http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/ analyzes the problem from the shell perspective but gives some insight on the underlying problem, that is the ARG_MAX size is the arguments plus the environment.

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

any variable arguments passed to the command line should be escaped with [escapeshellarg](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php)

I think, this should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the error comes from the fact, that you cannot directly execute a PHP file:

```
exec('/path/to/my/background-process.php '.$strReallyLongParamList);
```

You'd have to do something like the following, i.e. execute an actual program, such as the PHP interpreter:

```
exec('php /path/to/your/background-process.php '.$params);
```

But honestly, I don't think it's a good idea to use exec for such tasks, it's just a security risk too big if you don't know what you are doing. What exactly is it, that you are trying to do?

Comment: Don't "have" to call the php interpreter... just use the first line of the file to specify the interpreter:
`#!/usr/bin/php`